# QT Application on Debian 7 ignores keyboard

Tags: keyboard, debian, qt, xkb

I'm trying to get a teamspeak 3 client to run over a tightvnc -> xrdp session on Debian 7. As far as I know, TS3 uses QT as its GUI toolkit.

I can open the application and the window gets shown, but I am no unable to input anything by keyboard (writing in a terminal etc works perfectly fine). Mouse interaction works perfectly as well.

My terminal shows as its first output the lines

> Error: Couldn't find file "rules/?" in include paths
>   Error: 1 include paths searched:
>   /usr/share/X11/xkb
>   Error: 1 include paths could not be added:
>   /home/musicbot/.xkb
>   Error: Couldn't look up rules '?', model 'pc105', layout '?!', variant '', options ''
>   Qt: Failed to compile a keymap

whereas every ? is a character not displayable by my terminal

I found [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32760) on the QT page, but the error message is different and it's not about applications, but the toolkit itself as far as I understand.

I'm not quite sure where the error comes from exactly (vnc, xrdp, qt), but since keyboard input works for everything else I kinda suspect it's QT. I didn't include any logs since I don't know what could be relevant here, but if you need anything just ask and I'll post it.

Additional information:
Desktop environment: Xfce

ldd ts3client_runscript.sh:

> not a dynamic executable

ldd ts3client_linux_amd64 (after installing qt5-default (jessie)):

> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff651a5000)
>   libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00002b189077e000)
>   libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00002b1890e24000)
>   libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00002b1891472000)
>   libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00002b1891c9b000)
>   libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00002b1891fdf000)
>   libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00002b189221f000)
>   libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00002b1892436000)
>   librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00002b189264d000)
>   libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b1892856000)
>   libquazip.so.1 => not found
>   libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b1892a5a000)
>   libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00002b1892c78000)
>   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00002b1892f7b000)
>   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b189055c000)
>   libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00002b1893324000)
>   libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00002b189372d000)
>   libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00002b1893aa6000)
>   libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b1893dae000)
>   libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b18940b6000)
>   libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00002b18942cc000)
>   libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00002b18944f3000)
>   libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00002b189474a000)
>   libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00002b18949af000)
>   libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00002b1894c00000)
>   libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00002b1894f3c000)
>   libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00002b18967a9000)
>   libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00002b18969e7000)
>   libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00002b1896c86000)
>   libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00002b1896ea2000)
>   libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00002b18970ca000)
>   libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00002b18972dc000)
>   libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00002b18974df000)
>   libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00002b18976e6000)
>   libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00002b18978e8000)
>   libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00002b1897aff000)
>   libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00002b1897d05000)
>   libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00002b1897f08000)
>   libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00002b189810b000)
>   libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00002b1898312000)
>   libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00002b1898531000)
>   libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00002b1898733000)
>   libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00002b189893a000)
>   libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00002b1898b46000)
>   libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00002b1898d4f000)
>   libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00002b1898f53000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The newest version of TeamSpeak3 Client is broken, so you need to install older version, because there is no Qt5 libraries for some linux distributions.

Older Client versions:
x86: http://speedy.sh/GVXsH/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux-x86-3.0.13.1.run
amd64: http://speedy.sh/vxWfy/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux-amd64-3.0.13.1.run

Remember to not update TeamSpeak3 Client when you start it!

Comment: Nice find! With the version you provided I'm finally able to type again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The newest version of TeamSpeak3 Client is broken, so you need to install older version, because there is no Qt5 libraries for some linux distributions.

Older Client versions:
x86: http://speedy.sh/GVXsH/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux-x86-3.0.13.1.run
amd64: http://speedy.sh/vxWfy/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux-amd64-3.0.13.1.run

Remember to not update TeamSpeak3 Client when you start it!

Comment: I added the data, I see that it doesn't find the Qt libraries, am I supposed to install the from anywhere? I assumed the libraries that were included with the program were enough since the interface showed fine etc.

Comment: Yes you need to install missing libraries. But... I can't find it for debian etc. This libraries are only for ubuntu, any solutions from you?

Comment: I installed the package `qt5-default` (from the jessie repo) and now ldd finds files for every reference except for `libquazip.so.1` but it still doesn't work. I tried installing `libquazip0` (from the jessie repo as well), but that didn't help. Now I'm not sure whether the problem lies in this missing reference ir if that wouldn't even help either. I also updated the ldd output in the main post.

Comment: I also just realized that the script I use to call the teamspeak executable with already exports those libraries that ldd sees as missing. So I guess installing Qt was not necessary and all references are in fact ok.

Comment: Solved! The newest version of TeamSpeak3 Client is broken, so you need to install older version, because there is no Qt5 libraries for some linux distributions.

Older Client versions: x86: http://speedy.sh/GVXsH/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux-x86-3.0.13.1.run amd64: http://speedy.sh/vxWfy/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux-amd64-3.0.13.1.run

Remember to not update TeamSpeak3 Client when you start it!